# `git log --follow --graph` skips commits

Tags: git, git-log

## Setup

```
git version 2.11.0.windows.1
```

Here is a bash snippet to reproduce my test repository:

```
git init

# Create a file
echo Hello > a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m 'First commit'

# Change it on one branch
git checkout -b feature
echo Hi > a.txt
git commit -am 'Change'

# Rename it on the other
git checkout master
git mv a.txt b.txt
git commit -m 'Move'

# Merge both changes
git merge --no-edit feature
```

At the end, `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` prints:

```
*   06b5bb7 Merge branch 'feature'
|\
| * 07ccfb6 Change
* | 448ad99 Move
|/
* 31eae74 First commit
```

---

## Problem

Now, I want to get the full log for `b.txt` (ex-`b.txt`).
`git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --follow -- b.txt` prints:

```
...
* | 1a07e48 Move
|/
* 5ff73f6 First commit
```

As you can see, the `Change` commit is not listed, even though it *did* modify the file.

I think I have tracked it down to the implicit use of `--topo-order` by `--graph`, since adding `--date-order` brings the commit back, but that might be chance.

Additionally, adding `-m` shows the merge commit (which is fine) and the `Change` commit, but then the merge commit is duplicated:

```
*   36c80a8 (from 1a07e48) Merge branch 'feature'
|\
| | 36c80a8 (from 05116f1) Merge branch 'feature'
| * 05116f1 Change
* | 1a07e48 Move
|/
* 5ff73f6 First commit
```

## Question

What am I missing to explain the weird behaviour I'm witnessing?
How can I display cleanly all of the commits that changed a file, following through renames?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're being bitten by `git log`'s cheap and sleazy implementation of `--follow`, plus the fact that `git log` often doesn't even look inside merges.

Fundamentally, `--follow` works internally by changing the name of the file it's looking for.  It does not remember both names, so when the linearization algorithm (breadth first search via priority queue) goes down the other leg of the merge, it has the wrong name.  You are correct that the order of commit visits matters since it's when Git deduces a rename that Git changes the name of the file it's searching for.

In this graph (it looks like you ran the script several times because the hashes changed—the hashes here are from the first sample):

```
*   06b5bb7 Merge branch 'feature'
|\
| * 07ccfb6 Change
* | 448ad99 Move
|/
* 31eae74 First commit
```

`git log` will visit commit `06b5bb7`, and put `448ad99` and `07ccfb6` on the queue.  With the default topo order it will next visit `448ad99`, examine the diff, and see the rename.  It is now looking for `a.txt` instead of `b.txt`.  Commit `448ad99` is selected, so `git log` will print it to the output; and Git adds `31eae74` to the visit queue.  Next, Git visits `07ccfb6`, but it is now looking for `a.txt` so this commit is not selected.  Git adds `31eae74` to the visit queue (but it's already there so this is a no-op).  Finally, Git visits `31eae74`; comparing that commit's tree to the empty tree, Git finds an added `a.txt` so this commit gets selected.

Note that had Git visited `07ccfb6` *before* `448ad99`, it would have selected both, because at the start it is looking for `b.txt`.

The `-m` flag works by "splitting" a merge into two separate internal "virtual commits" (with the same tree, but with the `(from ...)` added to their "names" so as to be able to tell which virtual commit resulted from which parent).  This has the side effect of retaining both of the split merges and looking at their diffs (since the result of splitting this merge is two ordinary non-merge commits).  So now—note that this uses your new repository with its new different hashes in the second sample—Git visits commit `36c80a8 (from 1a07e48)`, diffs `1a07e48` vs `36c80a8`, sees a change to `b.txt` and selects the commit, and puts `1a07e48` on the visit queue.  Next, it visits commit `36c80a8 (from 05116f1)`, diffs `05116f1` vs `36c80a8`, and puts `05116f1` on the visit queue.  The rest is fairly obvious from here.

> How can I display cleanly all of the commits that changed a file, following through renames?

The answer for Git is that you can't, at least not using what is built in to Git.

You can (sometimes) get a little closer by adding `--cc` or `-c` to your `git log` command.  This makes `git log` look inside merge commits, doing what Git calls a [*combined diff*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_combined_diff_format).  But this doesn't necessarily work anyway, because, [hidden away in a different part of the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges) is this key sentence:

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.

Here is what I get with `--cc` added (note, the `...` is literally there, in `git log`'s output):

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --follow --cc -- b.txt
*   e5a17d7 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'feature'
|\  
| | 
... 
* | 52e75c9 Move
|/  
|   diff --git a/a.txt b/b.txt
|   similarity index 100%
|   rename from a.txt
|   rename to b.txt
* 7590cfd First commit
  diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..e965047
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/a.txt
  @@ -0,0 +1 @@
  +Hello
```

Fundamentally, though, you'd need `git log` to be much more aware of file renames at merge commits, and to have it look for the old name down any leg using the old file name, and the new name down any leg using the new name.  This would require that `git log` use (most of) the `-m` option internally on each merge—i.e., split each merge into N separate diffs, one per parent, so as to find which legs have what renames—and then keep a list of which name to use down which branches of merges.  But when the forks come back together, i.e., when the multiple legs of the merge (which becomes a fork in our reverse direction) rejoin, it's not clear which name is the correct name to use!

Comment: Shoot. Well, thank you for that comprehensive breakdown of the issue anyway :)