# Git merge fails on Segmentation fault

Tags: git-merge

I have big merge which involve many `inexact rename`, but it fails with the below:

```
Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (169817200/169817200), done.
Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (2106881938/2106881938), done.
Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (120035958/120035958), done.
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to restart my `VDI` but it didn't help. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: VDI? Are you working on Windows? On a local fisk or a network drive? With which version of Git?

Comment: Windows `VDI`, and on network drive.  git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: Would that persists with git 2.33.0.2?

Comment: I tried, and go the same error...

Comment: And would that persists, using git 2.33, on a local drive on the VDI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236925/discussion-between-vonc-and-arielma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236925/discussion-between-vonc-and-arielma), this happens only during a complex merge involving renamed folder and many files.

That is a job for the new [merge strategy ORT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309) ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin").
That merge strategy will become the default in 2.34, but in the meantime, with git 2.33.0.2:

```
git merge -s ort
```

> The primary difference noticable here is that the updating of the working tree and index is not done simultaneously with the merge algorithm, but is a separate post-processing step.
> The new API is designed so that one can do repeated merges (e.g. during a rebase or cherry-pick) and only update the index and working tree one time at the end instead of updating it with every intermediate result.
>
> Also, one can perform a merge between two branches, neither of which match the index or the working tree, without clobbering the index or working tree.
>
> The "ort" backend does the complete merge inmemory, and only updates the index and working copy as a post-processing step.

It does handle file conflicts and file/Folder renames much more efficiently than before (with the default "recursive" strategy).

Comment: Tnx a lot, it's clear. So how I can decide when to use this command or just simple 'git merge' command?

Comment: @arielma Starting with 2.34 (next release, Q4 2021), you won't have to decide. The ORT strategy will be the default one. A simple `git merge` will work, even in your case.

Comment: BTW, although the question was closed, I think it might solve it as well, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150777/git-mv-doesnt-work-as-expected-wrong-files-location

Comment: @arielma It would and I would have added the same merge -s ort answer.

Comment: what about history? I see that once I resolve conflict of file which wasn't exists and was created after the merge, all its history gone. Why git doesn't save it?

Comment: @arielma `git log --follow --cc` can help (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960010/6309), even though it is not foolproof: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46492159/6309

Comment: Not good :) doesn't show the real commit history of the file

Comment: @arielma Which is why https://stackoverflow.com/a/46492159/6309 mentions it is a hack. In case of a complex merge, getting back the full history is not a guarantee.

Comment: One more question :) I see the command in the solution knows how to handle new files and move them to right place, but that's not the case with folders. Is it known issue?

Comment: @arielma 2.33 should have taken care of folder renaming detection (as seen for instance in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227201/6309). Hopefully, 2.34 will take care of all corner cases, but it is possible some remains.

Comment: I'm using git version 2.33.0.windows.2, but note it's not folder renaming, but new folder which was added after the merge

Comment: @arielma Interesting. Not sure this particular usecase is managed by ORT though.

Comment: I will sent mail to git@vger.kernel.org, hopefully to get clear answer for this case

Comment: @arielma Let me know of the URL of your question on the mailing list (https://public-inbox.org/git/): I will follow that thread.

Comment: https://public-inbox.org/git/CANgfOPtz9JqCs-7z1DJnOqxnsGiQS6BBPD6tKTWnTpC0K3qZ9Q@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Comment: they replied on my ticket and I replied back. you can track it. other question, you wrote in the answer to use git 2.33.0.2, but in my organization the latest approved git version is 2.31.1. Can I use it as well?

Comment: @arielma 2.31 is a bit young for the new merge ORT: it is best to use the very latest, to benfit from all its features.

Comment: Ok, although I went thought the commits of 2.32 and 2.33, and couldn't find anything which related got OTT

Comment: @arielma OTT no, but ORT, most definitively yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66447468/6309

Comment: You are right as always :). 
From Git 2.33 Release Notes:
Repeated rename detections in a sequence of mergy operations have been optimized out for the 'ort' merge strategy. 
From Git 2.32 Release Notes: 
The test framework has been taught to optionally turn the default merge strategy to "ort" throughout the system where we use three-way merges internally, like cherry-pick, rebase etc., primarily to enhance its test coverage (the strategy has been available as an explicit "-s ort" choice).

Comment: Thread: https://public-inbox.org/git/CANgfOPtz9JqCs-7z1DJnOqxnsGiQS6BBPD6tKTWnTpC0K3qZ9Q@mail.gmail.com/T/#u